# Android Espresso: check the navigate up button is not visible

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have the following toolbar in an Activity with two fragments:

[image: fragment toolbar]

When I navigate to the second fragment, there is an up button showing, and when coming back, it isn't there, which is correct.
I just want to assert that it is NOT there with `Espresso`. To assert that it is there, I have used:

```
// The navigate up button should be displayed as a child of the toolbar
        onView(allOf(instanceOf(AppCompatImageButton::class.java))).check(
            matches(
                ViewMatchers.withParent(
                    withId(R.id.toolbar)
                )
            )
        )
```

However, I tried to negate it and do the following to assert that it isn't shown, but it doesn't work:

```
// The navigate up button should NOT be displayed as a child of the toolbar
        onView(Matchers.anyOf(Matchers.instanceOf(AppCompatImageButton::class.java))).check(
            matches(
                Matchers.not(
                    withParent(withId(R.id.toolbar))
                )
            )
        )
```

Any idea about how to assert it so that it works?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you testing visibility or lack of existence? The answer depends on whether or not it's still being returned in the layout.

Comment: Well it is actually the lack of existence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your original code returns a `NoMatchingViewException` when the button doesn't exist, I'd wrap that in a try/catch. I'm simplifying my code below - you'd probably want to make this generic and parameterized for reuse.

```
private fun toolbarButtonExists(): Boolean {
    try {
        onView(allOf(instanceOf(AppCompatImageButton::class.java))).check(
            matches(
                ViewMatchers.withParent(
                    withId(R.id.toolbar)
                )
            )
        )
        return true
    } catch (e: NoMatchingViewException) {
        return false
    }
}
```

I'd also suggest getting an `id` assigned to that button because the way you're finding it is pretty brittle. Finding by `id` would also let you use `doesNotExist()`.

Comment: thanks a lot! indeed this seems to be the only way. Unfortunately, the up button doesn't have an ID according to the layout inspector, and I don't know why